# Reshaping wide data to panel using reshape(base) only and keeping strings as time series identifiers

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, transformation, reshape

I've a data set similar to the extract below:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(geography=rep(c(LETTERS),3),December.1999 = runif(n=78),
                 January.2000 = runif(n=78),March.2000 = runif(n=78),
                 April.2000 = runif(n=78), February.2001 = runif(n=78))
```

My intention is to get a long data set resembling the format:

```
geography time           value
A         December.1999  0.26550866 
A         January.2000   0.77732070
```

Currently, I'm using the following code:

```
df_r <- reshape(df, varying = names(df)[2:length(df)], direction = "long",
                v.names = "Value")
```

which produces

```
    geography time     Value Geography
1.1         A    1 0.2655087         1
2.1         B    1 0.3721239         2
3.1         C    1 0.5728534         3
4.1         D    1 0.9082078         4
5.1         E    1 0.2016819         5
6.1         F    1 0.8983897         6
```

The data set I would like to build would have the column name in the **time** column:

```
                    geography    time            Value          
   A.December.199   A            December.1999   0.2655087
   ...              ...          ...            ...
```

and would meet the following qualities:

- **row name** would correspond to to the geography name + date column name
- **time column** would stored as a charter with the exact column name
- **value** column would contain numbers but also any potential strings and `NAs` that inadvertently may appear in the real data

---

*I'm not looking for solution utilising `reshape2`, `dplyr` or any other additional package. I would like to achieve this simple transformation using `reshape` as available in the R Stats Package.*

Comment: @akrun thanks very much for pointing that out, I fixed the code. I was trying to get what I wanted and pasted wrong version. The desired transformation is fairly basic and I would like to achieve it without relating on additional packages. There is no specific reason other than me trying to get `reshape` to work. I feel that I underutilise this function and often unnecessarily rely on `melt` or `dplyr` to do simple things to the data.

Comment: @akrun, Thanks very much, the `unlist` options works as advertised. I would be happy to accept, if you care to make it answer. Purely out of curiosity, would it be possible to achieve the same outcome using `reshape`? On principle, `resahpe` should do precisely that, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `base R` method, we can `unlist` the columns except the first one to create the 'value' column.  By using `data.frame`, we can get the 'geography' column to recycle based on the length of the `unlist` elements.  If we need to create a 'time' column based on the column names, we can replicate the column names by the `nrow` of the dataset.  Here, I use a convenient wrapper `col` which give the numeric index to the columns to replicate.

```
res <- data.frame(geography=df$geography, time=colnames(df)[-1][col(df[-1])], 
                    value=unlist(df[-1]))
res1 <- res[order(res$geography),]
row.names(res1) <- NULL
head(res1,3)
#  geography          time      value
#1         A December.1999 0.26550866
#2         A December.1999 0.01339033
#3         A December.1999 0.43809711
```

---

Or using `reshape` ('df_r' from OP's code), we can use the numeric index in 'time' to replace those values with the column names of 'df'

```
df_r$time <- colnames(df)[-1][df_r$time]
res2 <-  df_r[order(df_r$geography),-4]
row.names(res2) <- NULL
head(res2,3)
#  geography          time      Value
#1         A December.1999 0.26550866
#2         A December.1999 0.01339033
#3         A December.1999 0.43809711
```

If we need to do this within `reshape`, we can specify the `times`.  By default, it is `times = seq_along(varying[[1]])` (`?reshape`).

```
df_r <- reshape(df, varying=names(df)[2:length(df)], times=names(df)[-1], 
            direction='long', v.names='Value')
res3 <- df_r[order(df_r$geography),-4]
row.names(res3) <- NULL
head(res3,3)
#  geography          time      Value
#1         A December.1999 0.26550866
#2         A December.1999 0.01339033
#3         A December.1999 0.43809711
```

Comment: Would it be possible to inject the `time` variable to the original reshape command (in my actual code, I would prefer to replace the objects instead of creating another one)?

Comment: @Konrad Updated the post.  Hope that helps